# Filter objects that have a foreign key from another object - Django

Tags: django

I want to filter Employee, only those that have a ForeignKey, how to do it? My solution does not returned any results.

Models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ExperienceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Experience(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ExperienceCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views.py

```
experience_category = *ExperienceCategory object (1)*
#solution - final query
employee_query = Employee.objects.filter(experience__category = experience_category)
```

How to get employees who have a foreign key from Experience?

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work just fine, as an example to reproduce that

```py
first_employee = Employee.objects.create(name='First')
second_employee = Employee.objects.create(name='Second')

experience_category = ExperienceCategory.objects.create(name='sample_category')

Experience.objects.create(user=first_employee, category=experience_category)
Experience.objects.create(user=second_employee, category=experience_category)

employee_query = Employee.objects.filter(experience__category = experience_category)
employee_query

>>> <QuerySet [<Employee: Employee object (1)>, <Employee: Employee object (2)>]>
```

If you get an empty queryset it's because either there is no `Experience` instance with `related` category equal to `experience_category` in your database. To get the count of how many `Experience` instances matching this filter exist in your database you can run

```py
Experience.objects.filter(category=experience_category).count()
```

In the case I provided it would return `2`. Check first that this method returns a number greater than 0. If it returns 0 you should create some `Experience` instances first with the corresponding `category`.